# Can Fisher z-transformation be unbounded or scaled?

Tags: correlation

I'm trying to reproduce Fig 1. a) from this [paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature23007). My understanding is that the Fisher Z is normally distributed and practically bounded between -2 and 2, which correspond to correlation coefficients of -1 and 1. However, this paper reports z-transformed correlations between around -10 and 10 that correspond to raw correlations of -0.33 to 0.42 (from supplementary data). I have no clue how they are getting their z-transformed coefficients. Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How can a "correlation" have any absolute value greater than $1$?

Answer (score 1):

If their correlations were between -0.33 and 0.42, then there is a problem with the figure. An $r = .99$ converts to a $Z_r = 2.65$; an $r = .999$ converts to a $Z_r = 3.80$; and finally, an $r = 1.00$ converts to a $Z_r$ of infinity. As such, it is possible to have a $Z_r$ of 10 but only if r is close to 1.0 (e.g., .999999999).